# Android service for alarms

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

I am pretty new to Android and just started learning some concepts. I am trying to create an alarm clock for which im using my service class to initiate the alarm. But when I set the alarm time and have my app running in the background then I get the alarm triggered. At the same time, when I set the time and close my app(long press home button and swipe to close apps), I don't get the alarm triggered for the specific time that I had set earlier. 
Now I tried all possible ways to search the same question in this forum and I did get some few answers which did not solve my problem. Also I tried searching on github as well.. Tried them but no luck. 
I am not posting my code because it's just so a simple one that I had made as an example to understand service. Basically I wanted to know how the stock alarm clock in Android works and how is it triggering the alarm even if I set the time and close the app. Also what's the difference between start sticky method and start not sticky method? A simple with no complex terms definition will be appreciated. 
Could someone tell me properly how am I to proceed with this? Also a small tutorial would be appreciated. Thanks to every buddy here in advance.

Comment: For all those who are having the same doubt, I checked all the applications in android play store, there is no application that triggers or fires the alarm when the application is closed. But this is a poor response. I had thought atleast a couple of developers would ping me for the solutions. Anyways thanks and the question is closed.

Comment: Since this question is solved and there aren't any answers or information here that other developers would likely find useful, it's best to delete the question.

Comment: And unfortunately, questions do get buried because there are so many questions asked all the time. It helps if you format your question in a way to make it easier to read. One large block of text isn't such a great read.

Comment: @Jakar : Yeah true bro!Will do it from next time. Actually when I was posting this question, I was in my office.So, there are no codes with me to format it the way I wanted.And , this is reason for me to post a big chunk of text. Sorry for that and will make sure that next time, my questions are to the point explaining my try-outs as well.. Thanks for your response man.Appreciate that!

Comment: @Jakar : The reason I don't want to delete this question at least for next couple of weeks is that, it might be helpful for those who are tearing their hair out for the same question.